# How to best weight paint a curved polygon strip?

Tags: weight-painting

Is there a way to weight paint this polygon strip so that it bends in a more appealing way? I've tried subdividing the surface and still ended up with the same result.

Original object shape without rotating the bone:
[image]

After rotating the bone:
[image]

One idea of how this might look better:
[image]

**Update:**
With the accepted suggestion of using the gradient tool, the strip now looks better. I believe that you have to use gradient on more than one bone, and it might help to add additional edge loops on the parts that stretch the most.

Bone 1 paint:
[image]
Bone 2 paint:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i apologize that i don't know the exact key because i am using MacOS but i think it should be the ctrl (or alt) key on your computer, if you r using windows:

So in weight paint mode you can hold the ctrl(or alt) key and click and then move the mouse so you will get automatically a gradient.

Hopefully this helps.

[image]